# How to maintain the uniqueness based on a particular fieldin array Without using Unique index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the document like this.

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("aaa"),
    "host": "host1",
    "artData": [
    {
        "aid": "56004721",
        "accessMin": NumberLong(1481862180
    },
    {
        "aid": "56010082",
        "accessMin": NumberLong(1481861880)
    },
    {
        "aid": "55998802",
        "accessMin": NumberLong(1481861880)
    }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("bbb"),
    "host": "host2",
    "artData": [
    {
        "aid": "55922560",
        "accessMin": NumberLong(1481862000)
    },
    {
        "aid": "55922558",
        "accessMin": NumberLong(1481861880)
    },
    {
        "aid": "55940094",
        "accessMin": NumberLong(1481861760)
    }
    ]
}]
```

while updating any document, duplicate "aid" should not be added again in the array.
One option i got is using the unique index on artData.aid field. But building indexes is not preferred as i wont need it as per the requirement.
Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: have you look this **[$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)**

Comment: @Yogesh that doesn't work for adding subdocuments

Answer (score 3):

Option 1: While designing Schema for that document use `unique:true`.
for example:

```
var newSchema = new Schema({
 artData: [
    {
        aid: { type: String, unique: true },
        accessMin: Number
    }]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('newSchema', newSchema );
```

Option 2: [refer a link to avoid duplicate](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)

Comment: Thanx a lot. Can you please share hou can i set it using java?

Comment: This answer is specific to the mongoose api. The mongoose api, in this case, uses my answer of creating a multikey index.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#multikey-index), you may use a multikey index as follows:

```
{ "artData.aid": 1 }
```

That being said, since you *dont* want to use a multikey index, another option for insertion is to

1. Query the document to find `artData's` that match the `aid`
2. Difference the result set with the set you are about to insert
3. remove the items that match your query
4. insert the remaining items from step 2

Ideally your query from step 1 wont return a set that is too large -- making this a surprisingly fast operation. That said, It's really based on the number of duplicates you assume you will be trying to insert. If the number is really high, the result of the query from step 1 could return a large set of items, in which case this solution may not be appropriate, but its all I've got for you =(.

My suggestion is to really re-evaluate the reason for not using multikey indexing

Comment: Thanx for the reply. But i already mention that i wont need the index on the field. As data is so large and it is also not required.

Comment: This is a good option. But i have millions of data. This will take lots of time as updation done on large set in one go.

Comment: Any answer you find will be slow without multikey index, this is why it was made.